# problem in submitting form to cgi file

Tags: php, html

I coded a CMS for a client everything is ok except client said:

Use his previous shopping cart and embed that into the new design. The previous shopping cart file is shopper.cgi and I want to submit my form to that shopper.cgi

When I do this the file open dialog opens asking me to save the file or open the file.

Can someone suggest how can I make my form submit to shopper.cgi? I am running wamp server than ks

Comment: You should format your question better. It is hard to read. Please include the code of your FORM so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web server isn't configured to interpret/execute .cgi files. If you are running apache, add an [AddHandler cgi-script](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler) clause in your .htaccess or server config:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

Comment: i created the file .htaccess and wrote this line AddHandler cgi-script .cgi but now i am receiving the error i dont have permission on this server and i am using local host

Comment: Could be that your httpd config doesn't `AllowOverride FileInfo` for that directory.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you don't have apache configured to execute .cgi files, hence it's serving the file rather then processing it.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html